# Is it possible to include an iframe in a Gmail message?

Tags: gmail, iframe

Is it possible to include a web page in a Gmail message?

The reason I'm asking is that sometimes I have a Google Docs form I want to send to people and was wondering if I can embed the form in my email. I know I can email the form in Google Docs, but sometimes if I email to a group address it may not get through.

If you create a HTML page and put the following in it, you can see that it gets embedded. I wonder if I can do this in an email message.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="760" height="585" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Simon Brown, yes I did and the HTML code appeared in the message on the receiving end. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 6):

You can't really embed the iframe inside the GMail (unless maybe if you are using 3rd party clients) but there is a work around for this that you can try:

- Send the form to your GMail
- Then forward that e-mail to anyone you want (You can edit the page and removing the things that you don't want)

Run the tests by sending the form to yourself first and if you are using Plain Text while you are composing you have to change it to Rich Text before forwarding the original mail.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. I tried but Google Groups seem to have started sanitizing emails with HTML forms embedded (message is delivered but form is stripped). Email a form directly to a Google Groups address used to work fine but now it's ignored.

Comment: Turns out Google Groups never changed its policy on this. My messages were suspicious to be spam so they were pended and the moderator had to intervene. After 5 days he finally approved my messages.

Answer (score 2):

That would probably be a security issue so I doubt it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Not possible. I thought I would try to import the HTML into chimp mail as a workaround but even they don't allow it. It's not there fault though read below for full understanding:

https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email/

The quotation from the above link:

> Email HTML v. Web HTML
>   The viewing technology of a typical email client isn't as up-to-date as a web browser. Web browsers display interactive, dynamic content, and they update often. But interactive elements like Flash, JavaScript, or HTML forms won't work in most email inboxes.

If you want a more in-depth look then please read the [**article**](https://litmus.com/blog/the-tyranny-of-tables-why-web-and-email-design-are-so-different) which they link to.

[image: Here is also what MailChimp provides in terms of what is and isn't safe to use]

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant parts from the link you gave, in order for the answer to be better and full? That way, if the link is changed in a while - people will still know what was written there.